# Angular 2: Getting Updated Service Property from Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

My Angular 2 application uses route guards to restrict navigation to authenticated users. This happens in auth-guard.service.ts which is located in my AppModule

When a user signs in, an isAuthenticated property is set to true in user.service.ts which is located in a separate module named FrameworkModule.

User service is a provider in the framework module, which is imported in app module.

**My problem**: inside of auth-guard, fetching the isAuthenticated value does not work. It returns the value which was originally hardcoded, not the recently updated version. As I understand, this property is supposed to be a singleton, and the property values should persist. Am I missing some sinple fundamentals here?

**AuthGuard**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild, Router }    from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from "framework/services/user.service";


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

    //protect and restrict routes
    constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate() : boolean {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called ' + this.userService.isAuthenticated );

        let authenticated:boolean = this.userService.isAuthenticated;

        if (!authenticated) {
            console.log('not auth');
            this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
        }
        return this.userService.isAuthenticated;
    }

    canActivateChild() : boolean {
        return this.canActivate();
    }
}
```

**User Service**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { UserApi } from "framework/users/user-api";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class UserService implements UserApi{
    constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) {
    }

    isAuthenticated:boolean = false;    

    private url = 'https://api.backendless.com/09CC17DE-A1D2-5E58-FF59-1E73BAF40800/8B920997-09FC-BC85-FFA1-8211B837A300/users/login';
    private data = {
        login : " ",
        password : " "
    };


    signIn(username: string, password: string, rememberMe: boolean): Observable<any> {
        this.data.login = username;
        this.data.password = password;
        return this.http.post(this.url, this.data)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

    signOut(): Observable<any>{
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
        return Observable.of({});
    }

}
```

Comment: When does the action of signing in change the vlaue of isAuthenticated?

Comment: After both services have been initialized. Before auth guard checks is authenticated

Comment: One possible explanation is that the code setting `isAuthenticated` to true is being run after your guard is being utilized to decide whether or not this route is navigable.  I'm not sure what your signing in workflow looks like, but do you sign in from one component and then try to visit another?  I don't see anyone subscribing to the result of calling `signIn`, but if no one is subscribing to that, then I would suggest, upon successful authentication, using the `Router` service from `@angular/router` to redirect to where you want them to go after authenticating successfully.

Comment: Singing in happens in a framework module outside of the app module. The router and guard are located in the app module. On debugging, the User Service is updating the isAuthenticated bool as expected, but when the auth guard then checks it, it still is returning false somehow. It's like there are 2 instances of the service, but logging in the constructor shows it is only being hit once. 

There is something fundamental that I'm missing and I just can't figure it out.